# UNIX executable file downloaded from internet not set as executable automatically in Mac

Tags: macos, download, executable

I have a UNIX executable file which could be executed by just clicking it. I uploaded it to a cloud service, and then downloaded it on another Mac computer. Now this Mac doesn't recognise it as an executable file anymore. So I have to use the chmod +x command. Is there any way to keep the executable nature of the file intact, upon upload and download from the internet?

I could use the chmod +x command to make the downloaded file executable. But it was originally executable. I don't understand why this mode is changed upon upload and download from the internet.

Comment: Upload/download/sync/etc protocols often don't transfer file properties, including execute permission. Generally, you need to archive the file in a format that preserves at least execute permission, like tar.

Answer (score 1):

Different cloud services will have different behavior with respect to preserving the Unix file modes and ACLs. When uploaded to a cloud service, the files may be stored on a different type of filesystem or may not be stored as files at all.

On my mac I copied a file to iCloud Drive and the executable mode was preserved. Microsoft OneDrive also preserved the executable mode. Both iCloud Drive and OneDrive integrate with Finder.

You may consider using `tar` or `gzip` to create an archive file containing your executable. The archive format will preserve the file modes and the archive file can be stored on any cloud service.

Comment: Thank you, using a zipped version solved the problem as you said.